# Discord.js bot responds when mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my discord.js bot send a message when it is pinged. I was unsure how to do this so I referred to this code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '<@745648345216712825>') {
        message.channel.send('Message Here');
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't work.

Also, is it possible that my bot responds when a person mentions a specific user for example if I am mentioned by the user anywhere in a message the bot responds? If yes, can you show me how to do it?

Comment: If you replace the `<@745648345216712825>` with a simple string, like `hello` and then you say hello on Discord, does this work? Also, did you get any error message that can help?

Comment: What exactly does "this doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has a property called [`mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions), which contains all the channels, members, roles, and users mentioned in the message. You can use the method [`.has(data, [options])`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=has) of [`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) to see if your bot was mentioned.

---

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.content.includes("@here") || message.content.includes("@everyone") || message.type == "REPLY") return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) {
        message.channel.send("Hello there!");
    }
});
```

*The `message` event has been renamed to `messageCreate` in Discord.JS v13. Using `message` will still work, but you'll receive a deprecation warning until you switch over.*

Comment: Thank You... That works. However, if I ping @ here or @ everyone it still says Hello There! Anyway, I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: It does that because `@everyone` and `@here` mention the bot as well. You can check if the message content includes `@everyone` or `@here` and then return. [More info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: I am sorry. However, I am unable to understand what you're saying. Can you provide me with an example code?

Comment: @Jakye In my case its also replies on when i replied any message of it

Comment: @IrtizaKhanLabib Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the code. Can you try again?

Comment: @Jakye Working!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

discord.js just got updated you can use

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.mentions.has(client.user)) {
        message.channel.send('your message');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to check if only your bot is mentioned in the entire message is, regex. You can use this regular expression to check if only the client is mentioned:

```js
/^<@!?${<client>.user.id}>( |)$/
```

You can check message by using the `match` method of `String`. In our case, `String` is `message.content`:

```js
if (message.content.match(/^<@!?${client.user.id}>( |)$/)) {
  return message.channel.send("Thanks for mentioning me! my prefix is ...");
};
```