# Discord Js Bot Mention a user id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i am making a bot and i want to add that if someone mentioned me in there message then bot should reply something
i had tried many things but always failed
like i tried

```
if (message.content.includes("<@737177406376509520>")){
   message.channel.send('nice')
}
```

But that is not working and thats my user id
Help me to tell if someone mentioned me in message then bot should reply

`message.mentions.members.first()`

This also i had tried but i think it will only takes first mentioned
So help me to get it out

I want something similar like this if someone mentioned bot then it send this

```
if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)){
message.channel.send("Hello there! I am xD Bot");
}
```

Help me
Tell that if someone mentioned me in message then bot should reply something

Comment: hello, you can read this link and find your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825452/discord-js-bot-responds-when-mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.mentions.members` is a collection(map) of all the mentioned members in the message content. When you use `message.mentions.members.first()`, you are only getting the first mention. To check if a member was mentioned no matter at what position in the message, you need to get the whole collection in a variable like this:

`const mentionedMembersCollection = message.mentions.members;`

Then, use it in the `if` condition inside `message` event to check whether a specific member was mentioned or not using their `id`. A member collection(map) is mapped using `id` as `key` and `member` object as `value`.

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    const mentionedMembersCollection = message.mentions.members;
    if(mentionedMembersCollection.has('your-id') || mentionedMembersCollection.has(bot.user.id)) {
        message.channel.send('nice');
    }
});
```

The above code will send `nice` in the channel if either `you` or the `bot` or `both` were mentioned in a message. You can check for more people just like this using their `id`.

Comment: Should i add .has('<@123456>') or without <>@

Comment: Without the `<@>`

Comment: Tysm working 

Comment: Suppose i want a mesage to be print like this

Comment: You had mentioned (my username) , (amt of mentions) times

Comment: How can i do that

Comment: `\`You have mentioned ${message.mentions.members.find('your-id').username} ${message.mentions.members.filter(({ id }) => id === 'your-id').size} times`\`