# If a specific user is @ then say a phrase

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want it so that if anyone @'s user 1 then it responds with a phrase
What happens now is that any message sent by anyone will cause the bot to send the phrase.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type != 'text' || message.author.bot) 
      return;

    if (message.content === '<@user_id_1>' || '<@!user_id_1>'){
      message.channel.send(`<@!user_id_1> is funny`)
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js bot responds when mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825452/discord-js-bot-responds-when-mentioned)

Comment: He just constructed his or operator wrong. It will always be true because a non-empty string returns true.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type != 'text' || message.author.bot) 
     return;

  if (message.content === '<@user_id_1>' || message.content === '<@!user_id_1>'){
    message.channel.send(`<@!user_id_1> is funny`)
  }
});
```