# When I use any command, the response to ping a bot in a message duplicates. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm fairly new when it comes to creating bots for Discord, and I wanted to add a feature for it to respond to pings. I'm using [this](https://youtu.be/Sihf7B8D4Y8) command and event handler. After a few minutes of searching, I found a way to do it about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825452/discord-js-bot-responds-when-mentioned). I put it in the message.js file (this is the file created when making the event handler), seemingly everything works, but when I use a command, the number of ping response messages increases, that is:

- if immediately after starting the bot, I ping it, it will not respond
- if I use one command and ping him, he will answer once
- if I use two commands and ping him, he will answer twice

And so on

My question is: How to make bot always answer once?

This is my code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');


module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;


if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));


    

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord);

    client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return false;

        if (message.content.includes("@here") || message.content.includes("@everyone")) return false;
    
        if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("<:mentionic:878935275068334090> Oznaczyłeś/aś mnie!")
            .setDescription("Mój prefix na tym serwerze to `!` \n Użyj !help aby poznać listę komend!")

            message.channel.send(embed);
        };
        
      });
}
```

Main file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

require('discord-reply');
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
  require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})

client.once('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity(`7B jest super  Używa mnie ${client.users.cache.size} użytkowników tej wspaniałej platformy jaką jest Discord!`, ({type: "PLAYING"}))
});




client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the tutorial I was able to replicate the same command handler done in the video, and have come up with a soultuon for you.

What you basically did was put a message event, which looks for messages, inside a message handler which was added during the tutorial. Instead what I have done for you is implement the code which looks for commands in the pings handler itself

Put this code in your message.js file, inside the events/guild folder from the tutorial

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');


module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;

// If the message doesn't start with the prefix, doesnt mention the bot, or is sent by a bot, return
    if (
        (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) &&
            !message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) ||
        message.author.bot
    )
        return;

    // If the message has a ping mentioning the bot
    if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) {
        // Do your code here
        // You dont have to send a message, this is just for demonstrative purposes only

        message.channel.send("Hello world ");
        return;
    }

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if (command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
}
```